# Showing nav I previously hid with jQuery; jQuery versions?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple site that changes with certain resolution. Normally,  the structure is `header` and `nav` above `article` and `aside`, which are next to each other.

In CSS, there are 2 @media queries: one for when the site is smaller in width than 530px and one when it's wider.

When the width of the site is smaller than 530px, the `aside` and `header` elements are affected with `display:none`, and the only things left on the site are `nav` and `article`.

When this happens, a toggle button `#sidemenu` appears in the `article`, which hides/shows the `nav` and moves the article over it, the jQuery for it is this:

```
$('#sidemenu').toggle(
function () {
  $('article').css('marginLeft', '0')
  $('nav').hide()
}, function () {
  $('article').css('marginLeft', '20%')
  $('nav').show()
})
```

This works, but when the resolution changes back to something wider (I'm testing this by changing browser's window size), either the `article` is still affected by the `marginLeft` (if I left the toggle showing the `nav`), or `nav` by `$('nav').hide()` (if I left the `nav` hidden). It gets fixed by refreshing the page.

I tried adding this jQuery:

```
if ($(window).width() > 530 {
    $('nav').show()
    $('article').css('marginLeft', '0')
}
```

But adding it only causes the above toggle not to work. I also tried to show the `nav` based on aside's visibility, because it appears with wider resolution, but that led to the same issue.

I'm lost here, how do I solve this?

Also, I have 2 additional questions. This is my first time using jQuery and I managed to make this work with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

when I use version 1.11.3, the jQuery doesn't work. Which is the correct version to use? Why does it work in 1.5.2, but not in 1.11.3?

And the second question: It only started working when I moved the `<script>` at the end of html (just in front of `</body>`), why?

Edit: Managed to 'fix' the marginLeft problem by changing up the CSS a bit, so the margin change from jQuery doesn't affect the wider site. The hidden nav still remains though.

Edit2: Changed my jQuery so that it's compatible with the newer versions (got rid of toggle). The hidden nav still remains though.

Edit3: added some semicolons as recommended. Jsfiddle with the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/4372/

Comment: The `if` condition you added probably breaks your script because it is invalid syntax. You are missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that , but it didn't change anything. Adding it still causes the first script not to work.

Comment: Can you show us on jsfiddle what is wrong? Would like to recreate with HTML. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok, in this jsfiddle you can see the issue. If I hide the nav bar and then scale the site up, the nav remains hidden. https://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/4371/

Comment: Not gonna fix your problem, but you should get used to terminating your JavaScript commands with a semi-colon (;). JavaScript has some weirdness when it comes to self-terminating lines unexpectedly...

Answer (score 0):

The `toggle` event was removed in jQuery 1.9. This is why your code works when you use jQuery 1.5 but not when you use jQuery 1.11. See: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Instead of using `toggle`, you could try this:

**Javascript**

```
$('#sidemenu').on('click', function() {
    if ($('nav').hasClass('hidden')) {
        $('nav').removeClass('hidden');
        $('article').addClass('indented');
    } else {
        $('nav').addClass('hidden');
        $('article').removeClass('indented');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
nav.hidden {
  display: none;
}
article.indented {
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

Also, you should wrap your Javascript in a document ready block, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // Your code here
});
```

This will delay the execution of your code until after the DOM has fully loaded (see: http://api.jquery.com/ready).

If you were using vanilla Javascript, then you would use the following instead, which accomplishes the same thing:

```
window.onload = function(){
  // Your code here
};
```

Because you haven't done this, it was necessary to move your `<script>` element to the end of the `<body>`.

Comment: I changed the toggle and updated my post with the https://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/4372/ that is showing the issue yesterday. The real problem I'm having is that if I hide the nav and then make the page wider, the nav remains hidden...